# NSProgressIndicator Determinate although at a 100 is not full

Tags: objective-c, nsprogressindicator

I have an `NSProgressIndicator` which I use in the following way:

```
double ProgressLength = 1/(double)[[fh componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count]*100;
NSProgressIndicator *MyIndicator = _ProgressIndicator;

for (NSString *line in [fh componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
    [MyIndicator incrementBy:ProgressLength];
     // Some other staff
}
[MyIndicator setDoubleValue:100];
[MyIndicator display];
```

When the loops ends `[MyIndicator doubleValue] = 99.99999` so I thought that this was the reason why the bar was not `100`% full, so I specifically set it to `100`, but still the bar is not full.

Any thoughts???

thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

NSProgressIndicator has a *maxValue* property. If you set it to a higher value the bar will not be full at 100. This can be done in code and in Interface Builder.

Comment: So how much is missing for a full bar? 1% of the bar length or more?

Comment: If the bar width is small the missing part is also small. As the bar width increases the bit that isn't full increases as well. I would post a pic but I'm new to the forum and don't have a reputation of 10 or more..